# Remove image title when hovering using css?

Tags: css

HTML code

```
<a href="#page5"><img id="imgsrc_4" src="http://140.123.105.162:4001/h/8427d242759e6584152dc293579042b3f9c377a5-254818-1200-1677-jpg/keystamp=1441340100-47d38eef85/002.jpg" title="002.jpg" style="margin: 0px; width: 1050px; height: 1467px;"></a>
```

There are many image HTML like above. I want to search for title (001.jpg,002.jpg,...) of the image and remove/hide it using CSS.

How can I do that?

Comment: So you want to not show the tooltip when you hover over the image?

Comment: @Will That's right. Are there any way to do that using CSS?

Comment: Unfortunately, this is not possible with just CSS. You would have to use JavaScript to strip the title attribute. Or depending on your text editor, you could do a project-wide search/remove of those title attributes.

Answer (score 9):

A little late, but if someone is having same problem:

You can use `pointer-events:none` on that image, so the  link will still work but title won't show on hover

Comment: Might be a little late, but it'll help others who have the same problem and come across this question while searching.

Answer (score 3):

You can be do it by using jquery. you need to add class and on basis of that class you have to hide using jquery
here is demo..

```js
$(".img_bx").hover(function(){
 
        // Get the current title
        var title = $(this).attr("title");
 
        // Store it in a temporary attribute
        $(this).attr("tmp_title", title);
 
        // Set the title to nothing so we don't see the tooltips
        $(this).attr("title","");
         

    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="#page5"><img class="img_bx" id="imgsrc_4" src="https://angularjs.org/img/angularconnect-conf.png" title="002.jpg" style="margin: 0px; width: 120px; height: 120px;"></a>
```

Comment: Sorry I don't know anything about jquery. Using css is my best bet.  Is it possible to add the above code to the userscript?

Comment: there is not possibility with css you need jquery to hide title otherwise you have to remove title from images....